# Laravel + Vue/Nuxt

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

*Скажу сразу, php и laravel я не знаю, занимаюсь исключительно фронтом.*

Есть проект на laravel, фронт на vue (все в одном репозитории, возможно пресет лары под вью). На данный момент вся инфа (типа постов, статей), начиная с главной страницы, берется асинхронкой через axios по `/api`. А в изначальном шаблоне blade разметка, которую заменяет Vue.

Думаю можно не рассказывать почему данный подход *очень-неочень*. Поэтому было предложение перевести это все дело на Nuxt, но, как я уже упомянул выше, вся информация получается с бэка асинхронкой, поэтому какого-либо ssr-a крайне мало.

Вопросы:

1. Есть вариант передавать изначальную инфу в объекте `window.`, и делать уже изначальный стейт приложения без первого xhr запроса, то есть без асинхронки. 
   *Насколько в таком случае улучшится SEO страницы?*
2. Второй вариант, он мне не по душе. Встраивать vue компоненты в шаблон blade-a. Асинхронки в таком случае нет вообще, js, насколько мне известно, роботы парсят. НО... зачем в таком случаем вообще vue? Ибо пропадут все прелести spa. И тогда, можно было бы вообще все на blade-ы переписать.
3. Третий вариант. Каким-то образом засунуть в проект Nuxt вместо Vue, брать начальную инфу из `window.`. Видел [это](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-nuxt) и [это](https://github.com/skyrpex/laravel-nuxt-js) с вот [этим](https://github.com/skyrpex/laravel-nuxt). **НО**, насколько я понимаю, нужно шаманить с v8js, а я этого *максимально* не хочу делать. *Да и в принципе я не представляю как данный вариант реализовать.*

Какой подход посоветуете? Возможно есть еще варианты реализации SEO-friendly spa на Vue/Laravel?

*P.S. Заранее спасибо всем за совет.*

Comment: Приветствую. У меня вот обратная Вашей ситуация: не знаю Nuxt, но знаю Laravel. Поэтому не сильно понимаю вопрос в том месте, где "передавать изначальную инфу window."
У меня есть опыт разработки проекта nuxt.js + laravel. Мы делали вот таким образом: laravel - RESTapi - nuxt.js. Nuxt - крутится на сервере, получает данные из api, и все. Laravel - на отдельном сервере. Это были два независимых приложения, которые соприкасались в эндпоинтах. Т.е. ничего встраивать не приходилось в блейды, т.к. они не используются. 
В общем, это не ответ на Ваши вопросы, но надеюсь как-то поможет )